# Kill thread on change fragments

Tags: java, multithreading, android-fragments, interrupt

I have an activity with 4 Fragments and in each fragment I have a thread the 4 fragments are started together but I need to slide between them so that each one is visible, what I would like to know is how can I leave only the thread of the fragment that is being viewed and Interrupt the others, when you slide to the other fragments the same thing starts a thread and interrupts the others

Adapter

```
public TabManualAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0 :
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1 :
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;

        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tituloTabsManual.length;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tituloTabsManual[position];
}
```

}

Host Activity :

```
 viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

  
    slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.colorPrimary));
    slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    slidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor( this, R.color.black ) );

   
    TabManualAdapter tabManualAdapter = new TabManualAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabManualAdapter);
```

Comment: What do the threads do? Why do you have threads in fragments? This sounds somewhat unusual

Comment: The threads perform a serial communication with other devices on each fragment would be a different control thread